# Trying to retrieve xml tag value having namespace in it using mysql. Below is the sample xml code, want to extract value of dateTo field

Tags: mysql

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <dateTo xmlns="https://www.wr.com">12Sep2018<dateTo>
  <body1>Don't forget me this weekend!</body1>
</note>
```

Want to fetch the value of dateTo field from the above xml sample. Please help.
Tried below line of code but it gives me null value.
extractvalue(sampleXml,'//note/dateTo') or extractvalue(sampleXml,'//note/dateTo','xmlns="https://www.wr.com"').
While when I try to extract value of 'to' field or 'heading' field, it gives me required value.

Comment: Try `SELECT ExtractValue(sampleXml, '/dateTo');

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ExtractValue(sampleXml, '/tns:dateTo', 'xmlns:tns="https://www.wr.com"');
```

This worked fine finally.